# Element-ui view cant update immediately in slot area

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

```
    <el-tab-pane
      v-for="(item, index) in systemOptionsHeaderList"
      :key="index"
      :name="item.value"
      :lazy="true"
    >
      <span
        slot="label"
      >
        {{item.label}}
        <tips
          v-if="formHasModify"
          content="本页数据暂未保存"
        />
      </span>
    </el-tab-pane>


// The systemOptionsHeaderList: 

systemOptionsHeaderList: 
  [{
    label: '拨打策略',
    value: '1'
  }, {
    label: '资源设置',
    value: '2'
  }, {
    label: '打断设置',
    value: '3'
  }, {
    label: '静默设置',
    value: '4'
  }, {
    label: '分句设置',
    value: '5'
  }]
```

I use Element-ui "el-tab-pane" component

Now, I want use "formHasModify" (a Boolean Data) to control the "Tips"
component show or hidden

However, When I change the "formHasModify" the view can't update immediately

Comment: can you show your vue code?

Comment: The codes was very simple

I can update view by artificial (click) change tabs

Answer (score 3):

I solve this problem:

```
  el-tab-pane
    ref="elTabs"   // lock the ref
```

// When The data change, force update the component

```
let childrenRefs = this.$refs.elTabs.$children
this.$nextTick(() => {
  childrenRefs.forEach(child => child.$forceUpdate())
})
```

Comment: Thanks to Google for bringing this up, I have the same problem and was looking to solve it in the same way